# Zoom meeting resolution problem

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, zoom-meeting

this is my first question on this community.
I installed Zoom Client (ver 5.1.4) on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version, and it seems is zoomed, like the resolution is very low. It's the only application that have this problem, how can i fix it?

Thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem. I found a working solution [in reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/Zoom/comments/hat5af/linux_client_ui_elements_too_large_after_update/):

> Setting `autoScale=false` in ~/.config/zoomus.conf works!

Comment: Thank you Alex, it works! Next time I'll check previously the config file

Comment: Thank you you Alex!!!

Comment: I had the opposite problem (zoom client seemed to be zoomed out/tiny) and setting autoScale=true fixed it lol.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, still relevant in 2022, and Alex's solution didn't work for me. In the file `~/.config/zoomus.conf`, I found `autoscale=false` by default after installing Zoom on Ubuntu 20.04. I installed it from their Download center (.deb file, 64-bit).

This is how I made it work: in the same file, `~/.config/zoomus.conf`, find the following line

> scaleFactor=2

and change it to `scaleFactor=1`.

Comment: this option was not present in Version: 5.15.2 (4260) ~ July 2023