# Is it possible to get HD quality in Zoom videoconference client on ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, webcam, proprietary, video-streaming, zoom-meeting

I tried installing and running the latest Zoom client on 3 different computers running Ubuntu 20.04 with different speeds and specs: all of them display my own image in low, zoomed-in, grainy resolution using an HD webcam (logitech c930e).

On all 3 computers, running the Zoom client on Windows or Mac Os allows me to send an HD stream.

And yes, I did tick "HD" within Zoom client settings, so it's definitely neither the computers, nor the webcam, but definitely something happening between the zoom client and Ubuntu.

Other videoconference tools like Jitsi, Hangouts or Skype have no such issue on the same computers running the same Ubuntu 20.04.

This fix was for the UI, not the video stream, but I still tried it: [Zoom meeting resolution problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253288/zoom-meeting-resolution-problem) and it did not fix my problem.

Comment: Did you try updating your Webcam driver?

Comment: It's an UVC webcam, so normally there's no need for a driver and HD works fine with basically every single other software. I'm actually surprised that I seem to be the only one experiencing this.

Answer (score 2):

Try v4l2loopback to redirect your webcam's feed to a virtual webcam.

If you're lucky, Zoom will properly read from that virtual webcam

Assuming your webcam is at /dev/video0, we'll create a virtual webcam on /dev/video1:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 video_nr=1
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video1
```

to remove the webcam:

```
modprobe -r v4l2loopback
```

to test the virtual feed:

```
ffplay /dev/video1
```

## Why would it be different?

Webcams have 'capability flags' and some apps are buggy or picky when they see a flag they don't like. Thus if the virtual webcam presents a set of flags that's different from your original HW, perhaps it works.

That's why I added 'exclusive_caps=1' to the modprobe command. For example Chrome needs that setting to work properly.

If this doesn't solve the problem, you should repeat this procedure (remove v4l2loopback and insert it again) but skipping the 'exclusive_caps=1' param.

There are also other parameters that can be altered with v4l2loopback-ctl (such as format and framerate) which may end up solving your problem.

Altering the format may cause higher CPU usage or latency though, since the format needs to be converted in realtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that fantastically precise and useful answer. I will try and let you know how it went.