# I have red pixels on the screen with my webcam on zoom app. in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam, video-streaming, zoom-meeting

[Screen with Red Pixels in Zoom client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQqmm.jpg) I have a few (70 or 100) red pixels that spread all over the screen when I operate my webcam on Zoom client app. in Ubuntu 20.04 but not on Cheese/Skype/mjpg-streamer... with these 3 apps the webcam work superbly, any reason?

I resurrected this computer Imac late 2006 for a friend thanks to Ubuntu 20.04 with a particular config (32 bits EFI but with the latest 64 bits architecture/mattgadient.com) everything works absolutely perfectly except this little problem with Zoom Client... I am sure the problem is small and is with the config file but when I call it on the terminal with Gedit, the zoom config is Blank????

In `~/.config/zoomus.conf` is there anything related? And where can I find this file in the system or another file to amend, if I need to?

These few pixels don't bother my friend too much but unfortunately give migraine to his wife... and all their friends are on zoom!!!!

The projection of any zoom session on a different computer from this iMac is perfectly fine too.

[image: Red Pixels with Zoom]

The webcam Logitech C920s works perfectly well on SKYPE too!

[image: Skype Webcam]

Help anyone, in this vibrant Ubuntu community... any pointer? any directions? I really need to get that sorted... it really drives me insane!

Comment: some suggest to to Set autoScale=false in ~/.config/zoomus.conf but it doesn't works!

Comment: https://news2.x-itm.com/how-to-get-usb-webcam-to-work-with-ubuntu-20-04-and-zoom/
Poor Marisa, 3 weeks later... and no help... nothing!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253288/zoom-meeting-resolution-problem
Zoom meeting... maybe a resolution problem? Any help there?

Comment: Is the issue present in Zoom web client?

Comment: yep... and to be honest, i forgot about it as any interest never really manifest. red pixel and red pixel only on zoom client